# AWS API Gateway Appending Query String Twice

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to setup a simple demo endpoint via AWS API Gateway. Bellow is Terraform manifest which describes it.

It is essentially a `GET /demo/hello/world` endpoint which accepts a query string parameter `return_to`.

The terraform correctly creates all resources in AWS.

However, when I then make a request to gateway at `/demo/hello/world?return_to=bbb`, the backend service receives this request:

`/demo/hello/world%3Freturn_to=bbb?return_to=bbb`

As you can see the `?return_to=bbb` from API Gateway is being URL encoded as if it were part of the path and then another query string is appended at the end.

Anybody could help me out how to fix this? I have been going through all the settings for few hours and can't figure out what is the issue and how to fix it.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name        = "origin-${var.name}.${data.terraform_remote_state.setup.outputs.domain-name}"
  description = "Proxy to handle requests to our API test"

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "demo" {
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api"]

  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "demo"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "hello" {
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api", "aws_api_gateway_resource.demo"]

  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.demo.id}"
  path_part   = "hello"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "world" {
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api", "aws_api_gateway_resource.hello"]

  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.hello.id}"
  path_part   = "world"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "hello-world" {
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_resource.world"]

  rest_api_id           = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  resource_id           = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.world.id}"
  http_method           = "GET"
  authorization         = "NONE"

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.querystring.return_to" = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "hello-world" {
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_method.hello-world"]

  rest_api_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  resource_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.world.id}"
  http_method             = "${aws_api_gateway_method.hello-world.http_method}"
  integration_http_method = "GET"
  type                    = "HTTP"
  uri                     = "http://${lookup(var.demo-map, var.environment)}/demo/hello/world"

  connection_type = "VPC_LINK"
  connection_id   = "${data.aws_api_gateway_vpc_link.vpclink.id}"

  request_parameters = {
    "integration.request.querystring.return_to" = "method.request.querystring.return_to"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the last `request_parameters` appending it? What happens when removing `request_parameters` from `aws_api_gateway_integration.hello-world`?

Comment: @AndyShinn I tried removing request_parameters from both integration and method. And it doesn't solve the problem. I think the issue is with path_part matching the whole URL including the query string and then appending query string once more after that. As you can see the first query string is URL encoded, the second one appended after that is correct.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error. Having the query parameters in the `aws_api_gateway_method` and removing from `aws_api_gateway_integration` solved my problem

Comment: Wow. This saved me so much headache. Do you know why this is? Because I have other endpoints working fine where the query parameters are defined in both areas (Method Request and Integration Request).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue where API Gateway duplicates the same query parameter twice.

Here are the logs:

```
Execution log for request eddf82dc-45d2-441d-a041-00958f07eb32
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Starting execution for request: eddf82dc-45d2-441d-a041-00858j07eb32
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /v1/logs/my_customer
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Method request path: {clientId=my_customer}
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Method request query string: {keyword=InitApp}
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Method request headers: {page-size= 10}
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Method request body before transformations: 
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Endpoint request URI: https://my-api-eu-west-1.domain.com/v1/logs/my_customer?keyword=InitApp&keyword=InitApp
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Endpoint request headers: {page-size= 10, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=o4vpaghhyc, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_o4vpaghhyc, Host=my-api-eu-west-1.domain.com}
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Sending request to https://my-api-eu-west-1.domain.com/v1/logs/my_customer?keyword=InitApp&keyword=InitApp
Thu Sep 14 17:54:59 UTC 2023 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 266 ms
```

As you can see, the final created URI is:

```
https://my-api-eu-west-1.domain.com/v1/logs/my_customer?keyword=InitApp&keyword=InitApp
```

My API Gateway is as follows:

The Method Request Config:

[image]

The Integration Request Config:

[image]

I have used terraform with an OpenAPI definition to create the above configurations:

```
  /v1/logs/{clientId}:
    get:
      parameters:
        // parametes definitions
        // ....
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        connectionId: "1234"
        httpMethod: "GET"
        uri: "https://my-api-${region}.${domain}/v1/logs/{clientId}"
        requestParameters:
          integration.request.path.clientId: "method.request.path.clientId"
          integration.request.querystring.keyword: "method.request.querystring.keyword"
          integration.request.header.page-size: "method.request.header.page-size"
```

Removing the line :

```
integration.request.querystring.keyword: "method.request.querystring.keyword"
```

has solved my issue.

In summary, `integration.request.querystring.{param}` is for customizing how query string parameters are processed and transformed before being sent to your backend API.

It allows you to control parameter mapping, apply conditional logic, and perform data transformations as needed to meet your API's requirements.

So If you don't need all of these requirements you may not declare them in terraform IaaC or the AWS API Gateway GUI.